# Google Calendar API inserting event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

So, I downloaded this API library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git
And installed it on server, then set up very simple script to add an event to my google calendar, first part of script makes sure your connection is good, second part tries to add event. So, connection is good, but adding event is not.. it gives me back

```
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events: (403) Insufficient Permission'`
```

here is the script, can someone help?

```
<?php
session_start();        
require '../google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';     

$client_id = '574154490008-l55646vdpf62f7nrim9dodhtg6ssv4qv.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '574154490008-l55646vdpf62f7nrim9dodhtg6ssv4qv@developer.gserviceaccount.com';  
$key_file_location = 'someproject-9e09f9db466c.p12';        
$client = new Google_Client();      
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

// seproate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
    );      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

?>

<html><body>

<?php
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print_r($calendarList);
while(true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
        echo "<a href='Oauth2.php?type=event&id=".$calendarListEntry->id." '>".$calendarListEntry->getSummary()."</a><br>\n";
    }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}    

    //--------------- trying to insert EVENT

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary('Appointment');
    $event->setLocation('Somewhere');
    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2015-04-16T10:00:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2015-04-16T10:25:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('some@gmail.com');
    // ...
    $attendees = array($attendee1
                   //, ...
                  );
    $event->attendees = $attendees;
    $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
    echo $createdEvent->getId();



?>
</html>
```

Ok, So I just edited this line `$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";` I deleted ".readonly" so now I am getting eventId back as if I was inserting events successfully, but events are not showing up in the calendar.

Comment: If you are getting event id back then the event exists. Is it possible you are looking at the wrong calendar? The "primary" keyword means you will be inserting events into the primary calendar of the signed in user. Also try events.list() on "primary" to see whether you get them back..

Comment: well, I have only one calendar so it is probably primary, but I will check if I can just list all the events that are there...

Comment: Unbelievable! the events are there.. I am listing all the events that I inserted through the code... but I also inserted couple events in my calender and they are not being listed. So, it looks like I am indeed inserting them into wrong calender, but how is that possible if I have only one calender?

Comment: Try printing the "organizer" field of those retrieved events to see on which calendar they actually ended.

Comment: So, printed organizer array for each event and it showed something like this: Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer Object ( [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [displayName] => [email] => 574154490008-l55646vdpf62f7nrim9dodhtg6ssv4qv@developer.gserviceaccount.com [id] => [self] => 1 [modelData:protected] => Array ( ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: I am not sure what that means... But I don't see the name of the calendar anywhere... Also, as I said first part of the code makes connection to calendar and prints back array, but name of calendar also does not show up anywhere... so.. here is what first part of the code prints out:

Comment: Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object ( [collection_key:protected] => items [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [etag] => "1429204558100000" [itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry [itemsDataType:protected] => array [kind] => calendar#calendarList [nextPageToken] => [nextSyncToken] => 00001429204558100000 [modelData:protected] => Array ( [items] => Array ( ) ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: 574154490008-l55646vdpf62f7nrim9dodhtg6ssv4qv@developer.gserviceaccount.com is the calendar which gets the events. You are using a service account and the calendar of this service account has the events you are creating. I think you should switch to a normal Oauth2 flow with a user consent. Try giving a go to this guide: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: Yeah that is where I started, and it worked fine as far as displaying my events, but inserting would not work, so I started searching other way to do it...

Comment: If it didn't work then probably because of the readonly scopes ;) You should remove the ".readonly" part and it should work.

Comment: I removed "readonly" That was the first thing I did... That was my first edit to the code...

Answer (score -1):

You need share the calendar with your service account!

In the field e-mail put your e-mail (service account), that means like:

```
914304219907-rt42vptejtgg9fhb9btthdb2gbuctonp@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```